# Using Netbeans GUI Layout - items moving around

Tags: netbeans

I have a very busy GUI - lots of textboxes - the end result needs to be 21 columns with 24 text boxes in each column (1 text box for each hour of the day) I am over half way there.

I am getting frustrated with things moving on me as I add a text box or as I adjusted an existing box or title or label.

Is there a way to "lock down" things once I am happy with the look so that I know they can't move and then continue adding pieces?

Is there something I am missing with this problem. I am using (right-click) same size and align (left to column) functions to help. These help some. But I still run into the magic text box that when dropped in things move all around on me.

I am using NetBeans 7.3.1
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar problems and issues.

Two suggestions: 1) I have found that if I skip the order I place the textboxes helps with things moving. Meaning - if I had a column of boxes, i would place every other one then go back and fill in. It seemed to behave.

2) you might check into using the swing layout - check the Oracle site.

good luck

Comment: The every other placement did control the things moving around.